# Receive more than one message on more than one port Echo Server python

Tags: python, tcp, echo

I am writing a echo server and client in Python, that implements a simple number guessing game. I know how to multiplex using select, that's fine. The other server I wrote achieves this. But now I am writing a new server (which is fairly similar), however it accepts connections from two ports rather than one, one port for player client, and one for admin which I will use eventually for the who command, returning all connected players.
My problem is, that after sending the initial greetings message, the clients receive feedback from the server on the first send, `recv`. But after that I cannot send any more messages to server (nothing gets sent from the clients), I have been searching and playing around for hours, to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```python
# MULTIPLEX SERVER

import socket, select, time, random, ssl, sys, os

# VARS

EXP = 1
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT_P = 4000
PORT_A = 4001
BUFFSZ = 1024
BKLOG = 5
GREETS = 'Greetings'
INPUTS = []
OUTPUTS = []
CLIENT_ADDRS = {}
CLIENT_ANS = {}
CLIENTS = ""
_adm_rtnMSG = 'Admin_Greetings'

# Function to determine how far the player is
# from the chosen random number

def Within(value, target):
    diff = abs(target - value)
    if diff > 3:
        return 'Not even close, youth!'
    else:
        return 'Ooh, not to far: ' + str(diff) + ' away, keep trying...'

# END_FUNCTION

print('Server up and running...\n')

try:
    for p in PORT_P, PORT_A:
        INPUTS.append(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
        INPUTS[-1].setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        INPUTS[-1].bind((HOST, p))
        INPUTS[-1].listen(BKLOG)
except socket.error(value, message): 
    if INPUTS[-1]:
        INPUTS[-1].close()
        INPUTS = INPUTS[:-1]
    print('Failure to open socket: ' + message)
    sys.exit(1)

while True:
    READ_IO, WRITE_IO, ERROR = select.select(INPUTS, OUTPUTS, INPUTS)
    for r in READ_IO:
        for p in INPUTS:
            if r is p:
                (acpt_sock, addr) = p.accept()
                print('Connection established with ', acpt_sock.getsockname())
                CLIENT_ADDRS[acpt_sock] = addr
                CLIENT_ANS[acpt_sock] = random.randrange(1, 20)
            else:
                data = acpt_sock.recv(BUFFSZ).decode()
                acpt_sock.setblocking(0)
                if data:
                    if 'Hello' in data:
                        print(CLIENT_ADDRS[acpt_sock], ' random number is: ', CLIENT_ANS[acpt_sock])
                    acpt_sock.send(b'Greetings\nGuess a random number between 1 & 20')
                # drop elif here for admin cmd
                elif 'Hi' in data:
                    acpt_sock.send(_adm_rtnMSG.encode())
                else:
                   if int(data) == CLIENT_ANS[acpt_sock]:
                        acpt_sock.send(b'That was correct, Well done!')
                   else:
                        acpt_sock.send(str(Within(int(data), CLIENT_ANS[acpt_sock])).encode())
            else:
                print('Closing Connection @ ', addr)
                INPUTS.remove(acpt_sock)
                acpt_sock.close()
                del CLIENT_ADDRS[acpt_sock]


# PLAYER CLIENT

import socket
import re

# INIT VARS
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4000
INITSTR = 'Hello'
BUFF = 1024

# Set up socket
sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sender.connect((HOST, PORT))
sender.send(bytes((INITSTR), "ascii"))

print("Kirby Prompt FTW!\nConnected to Server via", HOST, "::", PORT, '\n')

rtnMSG = sender.recv(BUFF).decode()
print(rtnMSG)

# Simple loop to keep client alive
# to send and receive data from the server
while 'correct' not in rtnMSG:
    _guess = input("(>',')> ")
    sender.send(bytes((_guess), "ascii"))
    rtnMSG = sender.recv(BUFF).decode()
    print(rtnMSG)
sender.close()

# ADMIN CLIENT

import socket
import re
import ssl

# INIT VARS
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4001
INITSTR = 'Hi'
BUFF = 1024

# Set up socket
adm_sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
adm_sender.connect((HOST, PORT))
adm_sender.send(bytes((INITSTR), "ascii"))

print("Connected to Server as Admin via", HOST, "::", PORT, '\n')

rtnMSG = adm_sender.recv(BUFF).decode()
print(rtnMSG)

while True:
    cmd = input('$ ')
    adm_sender.send(bytes((cmd), "ascii"))
    rtnMSG = adm_sender.recv(BUFF).decode()
    print(rtnMSG)
adm_sender.close()
```

Comment: Your server `while` loop doesn't even run. And some of the `if...else` statements don't even make sense. For instance you have `if data` then in the `else` you compare `int(data)` which could only ever be a non-truthy value (`0` being the only such integer.) Perhaps you should look into something like http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html which might help you more logically segment your code.

Comment: The while loop actually does run. As it sends the greetings messages back to the clients, it just hangs after that. But thanks for the suggestion, checking that out now.

Comment: No, the code as you posted raises an exception because you have two `else` clauses for one `if` clause.